# Use dynamically loaded dlls from package function in global environment in R

Tags: r, dll, namespaces

I have a package called "aaa" that has a function like:

```
execute_query = function(arg1,symbol_list){eval(.Call("run_query",arg1),
                                           envir = .GlobalEnv)}
```

Here the run_query part is provided by a dll that has been loaded into the global environment in the functions .onLoad function:

`eval(dyn.load(file.path(dll_path,"liblib.dll")),envir = .GlobalEnv)`

This is successful and I get this dll listed when I use the `getLoadedDLLs()` function.

If I copypaste the function outside of the package it all works as intended.
However in trying to execute the execute_query from the package I  get the error message:

```
 Error in .Call("run_query", arg1) : 
  "run_query" not resolved from current namespace (aaa)
```

I guess that eval does not work when it comes to referencing linked dlls. How do I run a dll function from within a package function in the global namespace?

I have already tried to register the package using `library.dynam` but given the dlls are all part of a large external application and I cannot put it in the package directly this will not work. I am ok with hardcoding a dll path to the package so I would rather a rough solutions like executing everything in the global namespace if that works to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The answer here was to assign the function you want to execute into the global namespace. Thus we do:

```
execute_query = function(arg1,symbol_list){eval(.Call("run_query",arg1),
                                           envir = .GlobalEnv)}
assign("execute_query", execute_query, envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

Then this `execute_query` can be called from a package function or any other function.

It is not brilliant and would never fly on CRAN but it does work to use external dlls in a package.